# Can I make a gradient Polyline in React.js Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline, react-google-maps-api

Do you know how I can create Polylines in a Google maps view in my React app?

I looked into the google maps documentation but found nothing helpful to do this.
This is how it's done in Android: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes#polyline-customization. But I could not find the React version.

I can make a lot of lines with solid colors on each to kind of simulate a gradient, but that's not my ideal solution and it's not really performance optimized.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's currently no feature for Maps Javascript API that is similar to the mobile SDK which allows you to create a multicolored API. But there was a Feature Request that was recently closed (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825727) and you might want to put your use case and star the issue to add your interest.